# Stored procedure to update inventory

Tags: oracle

I don't know if i built my tables to create this correctly. I have to write a stored procedure to take in a `product_id` and a `quantity_purchased` from the tables below. I am only a student and just beginning and I can't figure out this procedure. I am probably just overthinking it but any help is appreciated.

My creates and inserts are below.

This was the beginning of my procedure and then I realized I don't know how to update my quantity on hand.

```
drop table INVENTORY cascade constraints;
drop table LINE_ITEM cascade constraints;
drop table PURCHASES cascade constraints;
drop table RESERVATION cascade constraints;
drop table PAYROLL cascade constraints;
drop table GUEST_HOUSES cascade constraints;
drop table CHURCH cascade constraints;
drop table BOOK cascade constraints;
drop table PRODUCTS cascade constraints;
drop table SCHEDULE cascade constraints;
drop table NUN cascade constraints;
drop table MONK cascade constraints;
drop table SHOPS cascade constraints;
drop table PRODUCT_TYPES cascade constraints;
drop table SHOP_TYPE cascade constraints;
drop table VISITOR cascade constraints;
drop table STATE cascade constraints;
drop table EMPLOYEE cascade constraints;
drop table VENDOR cascade constraints;
drop table VACANCY cascade constraints;

CREATE TABLE GUEST_HOUSES
(
    HOUSE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    ROOM_NUMBER NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    COST NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATION
(
     RESERVATION_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
     R_VISITOR_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
     R_HOUSE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
     ARRIVAL_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     DEPARTURE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
     R_MONK_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VISITOR
(
     VISITOR_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
     FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     ADDRESS VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
     CITY VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     V_STATE_ID VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
     ZIP NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE STATE
(
     STATE_ID VARCHAR2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
     STATE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CHURCH
(
     CHURCH_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
     CHURCH_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK
(
     BOOK_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
     TITLE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     PUBLISH_DATE DATE,
     AUTHOR_FIRST VARCHAR2(50),
     AUTHOR_LAST VARCHAR2(50),
     SUBJECT VARCHAR2(50),
     ISBN VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
     PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
     P_VENDOR_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
     P_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
     P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE
(SCHEDULE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
S_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(9),
S_SHOP_ID NUMBER(9),
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
START_TIME NUMBER(4,2),
END_TIME NUMBER(4,2));

create table PRODUCT_TYPES
(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
PT_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

create table VENDOR
(VENDOR_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
VENDOR_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

create table NUN
(NUN_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
N_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
N_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
N_VENDOR_ID NUMBER(9));

create table EMPLOYEE
(EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
E_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
E_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
HOURLY_RATE NUMBER(4,2));

create table MONK
(MONK_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
M_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
M_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
M_VENDOR_ID NUMBER(9),
M_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(9));

create table PURCHASES
(PURCHASE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
DATE_OF_PURCHASE DATE NOT NULL,
P_VISITOR_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
P_SHOP_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL);

create table INVENTORY
(INVENTORY_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
I_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
QUANTITY_ON_HAND NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
QUANTITY_SOLD NUMBER(9),
QUANTITY_PURCHASED NUMBER(9),
COST DECIMAL NOT NULL);

create table SHOPS
(SHOP_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
SHOP_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
S_SHOP_TYPE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL);

create table PAYROLL
(PAYROLL_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
P_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
HOURS_WORKED NUMBER(3),
PAY_DATE DATE);

create table LINE_ITEM
(LINE_ITEM_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
L_PURCHASE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
L_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
QUANTITY NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
PRICE DECIMAL NOT NULL);

create table SHOP_TYPE
(SHOP_TYPE_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
SHOP_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL);

create table VACANCY
(VACANCY_ID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
V_RESERVATION_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
BOOKED_DATE DATE NOT NULL);

alter table VISITOR
ADD CONSTRAINT V_STATE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (V_STATE_ID)
REFERENCES STATE(STATE_ID);

alter table PRODUCTS
ADD CONSTRAINT P_VENDOR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (P_VENDOR_ID)
REFERENCES VENDOR(VENDOR_ID);

alter table PRODUCTS
ADD CONSTRAINT P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID)
REFERENCES PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID);

alter table SCHEDULE
ADD CONSTRAINT S_EMPLOYEE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (S_EMPLOYEE_ID)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID);

alter table SCHEDULE
ADD CONSTRAINT S_SHOP_ID
FOREIGN KEY (S_SHOP_ID)
REFERENCES SHOPS(SHOP_ID);

alter table NUN
ADD CONSTRAINT N_VENDOR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (N_VENDOR_ID)
REFERENCES VENDOR(VENDOR_ID);

alter table MONK
ADD CONSTRAINT M_VENDOR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (M_VENDOR_ID)
REFERENCES VENDOR(VENDOR_ID);

alter table MONK
ADD CONSTRAINT M_EMPLOYEE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (M_EMPLOYEE_ID)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID);

alter table PURCHASES
ADD CONSTRAINT P_VISITOR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (P_VISITOR_ID)
REFERENCES VISITOR(VISITOR_ID);

alter table PURCHASES
ADD CONSTRAINT P_SHOP_ID
FOREIGN KEY (P_SHOP_ID)
REFERENCES SHOPS(SHOP_ID);

alter table SHOPS
ADD CONSTRAINT S_SHOP_TYPE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (S_SHOP_TYPE_ID)
REFERENCES SHOP_TYPE(SHOP_TYPE_ID);

alter table PAYROLL
ADD CONSTRAINT P_EMPLOYEE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (P_EMPLOYEE_ID)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID);

alter table LINE_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT L_PURCHASE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (L_PURCHASE_ID)
REFERENCES PURCHASES(PURCHASE_ID);

alter table LINE_ITEM
ADD CONSTRAINT L_PRODUCT_ID
FOREIGN KEY (L_PRODUCT_ID)
REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID);

alter table INVENTORY
ADD CONSTRAINT I_PRODUCT_ID
FOREIGN KEY (I_PRODUCT_ID)
REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID);

alter table RESERVATION
ADD CONSTRAINT R_MONK_ID
FOREIGN KEY (R_MONK_ID)
REFERENCES MONK(MONK_ID);

alter table RESERVATION
ADD CONSTRAINT R_VISITOR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (R_VISITOR_ID)
REFERENCES VISITOR(VISITOR_ID);

alter table RESERVATION
ADD CONSTRAINT R_HOUSE_ID
FOREIGN KEY (R_HOUSE_ID)
REFERENCES GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID);

alter table VACANCY
ADD CONSTRAINT V_RESERVATION_ID
FOREIGN KEY (V_RESERVATION_ID)
REFERENCES RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID);


INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('OR', 'OREGON');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('WA', 'WASHINGTON');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('CA', 'CALIFORNIA');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('AK', 'ALASKA');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('ID', 'IDAHO');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('NY', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('UT', 'UTAH');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('AL', 'ALABAMA');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('AZ', 'ARIZONA');
INSERT INTO STATE (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME) VALUES ('AR', 'ARKANSAS');
INSERT INTO SHOP_TYPE(SHOP_TYPE_ID, SHOP_TYPE_NAME) VALUES (123, 'SHOPS');
INSERT INTO SHOP_TYPE(SHOP_TYPE_ID, SHOP_TYPE_NAME) VALUES (456, 'RESTAURANTS');
INSERT INTO CHURCH(CHURCH_ID, CHURCH_NAME) VALUES (287, 'BEST CHURCH EVER');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (01, 'TEA');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (02, 'COOKIES');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (03, 'SNACKS');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (04, 'BOOKS');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (05, 'CLOTHES');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (06, 'OFFICE SUPPLIES');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (07, 'MEALS');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (08, 'ACCESSORIES');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_TYPES(PRODUCT_TYPE_ID, PT_NAME) VALUES (09, 'LUGGAGE');
INSERT INTO VENDOR(VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME) VALUES (10, 'STAPLES');
INSERT INTO VENDOR(VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME) VALUES (11, 'MCDONALD WHOLESALE');
INSERT INTO VENDOR(VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME) VALUES (12, 'BARNEYS');
INSERT INTO VENDOR(VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME) VALUES (13, 'SALLY NUNSEN');
INSERT INTO VENDOR(VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME) VALUES (14, 'EDWARD MONKERSON');
INSERT INTO NUN(NUN_ID, N_FIRST_NAME, N_LAST_NAME, N_VENDOR_ID) VALUES (15, 'SALLY', 'NUNSEN', 13);
INSERT INTO NUN(NUN_ID, N_FIRST_NAME, N_LAST_NAME) VALUES (16, 'CARLEEN', 'CABELSON');
INSERT INTO NUN(NUN_ID, N_FIRST_NAME, N_LAST_NAME) VALUES (17, 'GLENDA', 'GILBERT');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID, E_FIRST_NAME, E_LAST_NAME, HOURLY_RATE) VALUES (18, 'ROSE', 'PETERSON', 15.25);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID, E_FIRST_NAME, E_LAST_NAME, HOURLY_RATE) VALUES (19, 'HANNAH', 'SOBRINSKI', 12.50);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID, E_FIRST_NAME, E_LAST_NAME, HOURLY_RATE) VALUES (20, 'MITCH', 'HILBERT', 14.75);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID, E_FIRST_NAME, E_LAST_NAME, HOURLY_RATE) VALUES (21, 'JOE', 'PLANK', 13.00);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID, E_FIRST_NAME, E_LAST_NAME, HOURLY_RATE) VALUES (22, 'EDWARD', 'MONKERSON', 20.50);
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME, M_VENDOR_ID) VALUES (23, 'EDWARD', 'MONKERSON', 14);
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (24, 'JOE', 'PLANK');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (25, 'RICHARD', 'NIXON');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (26, 'JOSEPH', 'BIDEN');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (27, 'JOHN', 'SMITH');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (28, 'GEORGE', 'WASHINGTON');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (29, 'WINSTON', 'CHURCHILL');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (30, 'DAVID', 'BECKHAM');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (31, 'JERAMY', 'CARD');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (32, 'BILL', 'BELLAMY');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (33, 'RYAN', 'TUCKER');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (34, 'RINGO', 'STARR');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (35, 'BRUCE', 'WAYNE');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (36, 'DICK', 'VAN DYKE');
INSERT INTO MONK(MONK_ID, M_FIRST_NAME, M_LAST_NAME) VALUES (37, 'JAMES', 'DEAN');
INSERT INTO SHOPS(SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME, S_SHOP_TYPE_ID) VALUES (38, 'MONASTIC SHOP', 123);
INSERT INTO SHOPS(SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME, S_SHOP_TYPE_ID) VALUES (39, 'GRANGE RESTAURANT', 456);
INSERT INTO SHOPS(SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME, S_SHOP_TYPE_ID) VALUES (40, 'GIFT SHOP', 123);
INSERT INTO SHOPS(SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME, S_SHOP_TYPE_ID) VALUES (41, 'BOOK SHOP', 123);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (42, 01, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (43, 02, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (44, 03, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (45, 04, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (46, 05, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (47, 06, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (48, 07, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (49, 08, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (50, 09, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (51, 10, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (52, 11, 60.00);
INSERT INTO GUEST_HOUSES(HOUSE_ID, ROOM_NUMBER, COST) VALUES (53, 12, 60.00);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (54, 'ERICA', 'CARD', '123 MAIN ST', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'OR', 97477);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (55, 'RICK', 'JAMES', '567 ALABASTER LN', 'PORT ORCHARD', 'WA', 99567);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (56, 'SANTA', 'CLAUSE', '248 NORTH POLE LOOP', 'NORTH POLE', 'AK', 57489);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (57, 'HARRY', 'HENDERSON', '23185 10TH AVE', 'NEW YORK', 'NY', 01587);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (58, 'CHRIS', 'SWIRES', '5165 YOLANDA RD', 'GREENBOUGH', 'AL', 25478);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (59, 'MICHELE', 'WURGES', '8456 ANCHOR WAY', 'POULSBO', 'WA', 92475);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (60, 'MONICA', 'ROSENKRANCE', '3547 HAYDEN BRIDGE DR', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'OR', 97477);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (61, 'ALLEN', 'MASTERS', '14785 MEADOW LARK RD', 'BOISE', 'ID', 84222);
INSERT INTO VISITOR(VISITOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, V_STATE_ID, ZIP) VALUES (62, 'MICHAEL', 'JACKSON', '61002 NEVERLAND ST', 'SANTA CRUZ', 'CA', 99854);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (63, 10, 'PENS', 06);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (64, 11, 'OATMEAL RAISIN', 02);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (65, 12, 'T-SHIRT', 05);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (66, 13, 'RED SCARF', 08);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (67, 14, 'HAND SEWN BAG', 09);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID, P_VENDOR_ID, P_NAME, P_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID) VALUES (68, 11, 'STEAK and EGGS', 07);
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(SCHEDULE_ID, S_EMPLOYEE_ID, S_SHOP_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME) VALUES (69, 18, 39, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 08.00, 21.00);
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(SCHEDULE_ID, S_EMPLOYEE_ID, S_SHOP_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME) VALUES (70, 19, 40, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 08.00, 21.00);
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(SCHEDULE_ID, S_EMPLOYEE_ID, S_SHOP_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME) VALUES (71, 22, 38, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 08.00, 21.00);
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(SCHEDULE_ID, S_EMPLOYEE_ID, S_SHOP_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME) VALUES (72, 21, 41, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 08.00, 21.00);
INSERT INTO PURCHASES(PURCHASE_ID, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, P_VISITOR_ID, P_SHOP_ID) VALUES (73, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 54, 40);
INSERT INTO PURCHASES(PURCHASE_ID, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, P_VISITOR_ID, P_SHOP_ID) VALUES (74, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 54, 38);
INSERT INTO PURCHASES(PURCHASE_ID, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, P_VISITOR_ID, P_SHOP_ID) VALUES (75, TO_DATE('07/15/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 59, 39);
INSERT INTO PURCHASES(PURCHASE_ID, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, P_VISITOR_ID, P_SHOP_ID) VALUES (76, TO_DATE('08/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 56, 40);
INSERT INTO LINE_ITEM(LINE_ITEM_ID, L_PURCHASE_ID, L_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE) VALUES (77, 73, 63, 5, 3.00);
INSERT INTO LINE_ITEM(LINE_ITEM_ID, L_PURCHASE_ID, L_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE) VALUES (78, 74, 67, 2, 25.50);
INSERT INTO LINE_ITEM(LINE_ITEM_ID, L_PURCHASE_ID, L_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE) VALUES (79, 75, 68, 1, 12.25);
INSERT INTO LINE_ITEM(LINE_ITEM_ID, L_PURCHASE_ID, L_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE) VALUES (80, 76, 65, 3, 13.75);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (81, 63, 25, 5, 0, 1.15);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (82, 64, 12, 0, 0, .75);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (83, 65, 32, 3, 0, 5.00);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (84, 66, 11, 0, 0, 7.00);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (85, 67, 65, 2, 0, 15.00);
INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_ID, I_PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, QUANTITY_SOLD, QUANTITY_PURCHASED, COST) VALUES (86, 68, 12, 1, 0, 7.00);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (87, 54, 42, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/14/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 26);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (88, 58, 43, TO_DATE('06/15/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 27);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (89, 57, 44, TO_DATE('07/25/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('07/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 28);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (90, 59, 45, TO_DATE('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('07/16/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 29);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (91, 56, 46, TO_DATE('08/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('08/10/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 30);
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(RESERVATION_ID, R_VISITOR_ID, R_HOUSE_ID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE, R_MONK_ID) VALUES (92, 54, 47, TO_DATE('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('07/30/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 31);
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (92, 87, TO_DATE('06/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (94, 87, TO_DATE('06/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (95, 87, TO_DATE('06/03/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (96, 87, TO_DATE('06/04/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (97, 87, TO_DATE('06/05/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (98, 87, TO_DATE('06/06/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (99, 87, TO_DATE('06/07/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (100, 87, TO_DATE('06/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (101, 87, TO_DATE('06/09/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (102, 87, TO_DATE('06/10/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (103, 87, TO_DATE('06/11/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (104, 87, TO_DATE('06/12/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (105, 87, TO_DATE('06/13/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (106, 88, TO_DATE('06/15/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (107, 88, TO_DATE('06/16/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (108, 88, TO_DATE('06/17/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (109, 88, TO_DATE('06/18/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (110, 88, TO_DATE('06/19/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (111, 88, TO_DATE('06/20/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (112, 88, TO_DATE('06/21/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (113, 88, TO_DATE('06/22/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (114, 88, TO_DATE('06/23/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (115, 88, TO_DATE('06/24/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (116, 88, TO_DATE('06/25/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (117, 88, TO_DATE('06/26/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (118, 88, TO_DATE('06/27/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (119, 88, TO_DATE('06/28/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (120, 88, TO_DATE('06/29/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (121, 89, TO_DATE('07/25/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (122, 89, TO_DATE('07/26/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (123, 89, TO_DATE('07/27/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (124, 89, TO_DATE('07/28/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (125, 89, TO_DATE('07/29/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (126, 90, TO_DATE('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (127, 90, TO_DATE('07/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (128, 90, TO_DATE('07/03/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (129, 90, TO_DATE('07/04/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (130, 90, TO_DATE('07/05/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (131, 90, TO_DATE('07/06/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (132, 90, TO_DATE('07/07/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (133, 90, TO_DATE('07/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (134, 90, TO_DATE('07/09/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (135, 90, TO_DATE('07/10/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (136, 90, TO_DATE('07/11/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (137, 90, TO_DATE('07/12/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (138, 90, TO_DATE('07/13/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (139, 90, TO_DATE('07/14/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (140, 91, TO_DATE('08/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (141, 91, TO_DATE('08/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (142, 91, TO_DATE('08/03/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (143, 91, TO_DATE('08/04/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (144, 91, TO_DATE('08/05/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (145, 91, TO_DATE('08/06/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (146, 91, TO_DATE('08/07/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (147, 91, TO_DATE('08/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (148, 91, TO_DATE('08/09/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (149, 92, TO_DATE('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (150, 92, TO_DATE('07/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (151, 92, TO_DATE('07/03/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (152, 92, TO_DATE('07/04/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (153, 92, TO_DATE('07/05/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (154, 92, TO_DATE('07/06/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (155, 92, TO_DATE('07/07/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (156, 92, TO_DATE('07/08/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (157, 92, TO_DATE('07/09/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (158, 92, TO_DATE('07/10/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (159, 92, TO_DATE('07/11/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (160, 92, TO_DATE('07/12/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (161, 92, TO_DATE('07/13/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (162, 92, TO_DATE('07/14/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (163, 92, TO_DATE('07/15/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (164, 92, TO_DATE('07/16/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (165, 92, TO_DATE('07/17/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (166, 92, TO_DATE('07/18/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (167, 92, TO_DATE('07/19/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (168, 92, TO_DATE('07/20/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (169, 92, TO_DATE('07/21/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (170, 92, TO_DATE('07/22/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (171, 92, TO_DATE('07/23/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (172, 92, TO_DATE('07/24/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (173, 92, TO_DATE('07/25/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (174, 92, TO_DATE('07/26/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')); 
INSERT INTO VACANCY(VACANCY_ID, V_RESERVATION_ID, BOOKED_DATE) VALUES (175, 92, TO_DATE('07/27/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Comment: The qty purchased is a field for what the shop purchases for inventory. Qty sold is what customer have bought. The nuns, monks, and churches are just part of the project for school. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your procedure could just update `INVENTORY` using

```
update inventory
set    quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand - p_quantity
     , quantity_sold = quantity_sold + p_quantity
     , quantity_purchased = quantity_purchased + p_quantity
where  i_product_purchased = p_product_id
```

with `p_product_id` and `p_quantity` passed in as parameters.

I am not sure what the difference is between `quantity_sold` and `quantity_purchased`.

If you want to record the purchase in `PURCHASES` then you will need to know the visitor and shop, but perhaps that is a task for another procedure.

I'm not sure what Monks, Nuns and Churches have to do with the question.